# Showing errors in yii2 form validation

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I would like to do custom validation in yii2 but this doesnt work.

What i would like is to validate whenever truck status is not 17 or 18 that is if eg its 12 this error should be returned, but the error is always displayed

```
  public function validateRegno()
{
    $truck = TblTrucks::find()->where(["reg_no"=>$this->reg_no])->all();

    if ($truck) {
        if(!$truck->truck_status ==18 || !$truck->truck_status ==17){
            $this->addError('reg_no', 'The truck is not yet cleared by customer service');
        }


    }
}
```

These are the model rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reg_no', 'truck_category', 'added_by', 'truck_status', 'driver_name'], 'required'],
        [['truck_category', 'added_by', 'truck_status', 'is_normal'], 'integer'],
        [['added_on'], 'safe'],
        [['reg_no'], 'string', 'max' => 50],

        ['reg_no', 'validateRegno','on' => 'create'],

}
```

This is my form

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(),
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        //'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => ['truck/validate'],

    ]); ?>
```

In the controller

```
(truck/validate)
  public function actionValidate(){
    $model = new TblTrucks();
    $model->scenario = 'create';
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if (!$model->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->response->format='json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `'enableAjaxValidation' => true` on form and also add `if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
      }` in action part

Comment: but it fails to do so

Comment: are you getting error?

Comment: No error is returned what happens is that the or (||) condition doesnt work, When testing with a single condition of eg 17 it works but when testing with both conditions it doesnt work

Comment: Correct the condition to `if (!in_array($truck->truck_status, [17, 18]))`

Comment: Bizley post this as an answer, it works.... ill mark it

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Bizely's answer is working for you!!?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom validation method should be like below.

```
    public function validateRegno()
{
    $truck = TblTrucks::find()->where(["reg_no"=>$this->reg_no])->all();

    if ($truck) {
        if(!$truck->truck_status ==18 || !$truck->truck_status ==17){
            $this->addError('reg_no', 'The truck is not yet cleared by customer service');
        }


    }
}
```

I hope in your model, `$this->reg_no` is the primary key field I mean auto increment field. So while creating new record, it will be empty.

**Edited:**

As per your comment, `$this->reg_no` is not a primary key in model. While retrieving the records by using `all()` it will return the array of records. Please refer this link - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#all()-detail So you have to iterate the records to check the each truck status.

Or otherwise `$this->reg_no` is unique in the table, you have to use `one()` method to retrieve the record. it will return single record from the table. Please refer the documentation for `one()` - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#one()-detail

Comment: How is it different from what i have posted in the question and it fails

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Please check the *validateRegno* method, I removed the query and if condition also. In your case it's no need I feel.

Comment: Whats happening is that during registration ama checking to see if there is a truck having a similar reg_no so we cant assume that empty, the reg_no is not an auto increment

Comment: The query is necessary for checking if truck is registered and exists

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Ok. let me change my answer according to your requirement